# jQuery Autocomplete - Show Data Based on Selection

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I have a standard jQuery autocomplete setup similar to the below:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    minLength: 5 ,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
         alert(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

What I would like is, when the value is chosen, a data-table within the page appears and get populated with data from a database using the value as a search parameter.

So for instance if I select "`RED`", the table would then show and display data from a query such as `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN='RED'`

The query is simplified but can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You mean based on the input, you want to pull content from the DB?

Comment: Yes. So you have an input field. Behind this sits a list of values. You select a value and based on that, a DIV/Table shows with data from a database using a query where the value that has been chosen is a parameter.

A hack would be to have an iFrame and change the SRC of the iFrame to incorporate the parameter but was hoping there was a slicker way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you should request a kind of `search` page which will act as `JSON` endpoint for e.g.

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    minLength: 5 ,
    select: function( event, ui ) {

      var _value = ui.item.value;

      $.post('services/populate_table.php', // endpoint URL
             { someParameterToTransmit: _value  }, // some data to transmit
             function(data) { // on complete handler
               $('.result').html(data); // populate retrieved data in any form you need
             } // on complete function
      ); // post
    } // on select (autocomplete)
}); // autocomplete
```

Data from `endpoint` also can be retrieved as `JSON`.

You can read [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more information about request method.

Comment: @JanuszJasinski, You are welcome. I've updated code a bit with comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post).

For example, your jQuery would be:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    minLength: 5 ,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $.post("autocomplete.php", { option: ui.item.value }, function(data){
            $("table").html( data[0] );
            // sets the content of a table element to the first matched row
        });
    }
});
```

And in `autocomplete.php`, you would have something like this:

```
// DB connect

// use $_POST['option'] here for the selected option
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth);
print $r;
```

What we do here is request the page `autocomplete.php` and POST the data, which in this case is the selected value. `autocomplete.php` grabs that POSTed value and searches the database (you can customize that query to fit your needs). The page then prints an array of the matched rows, which is the data received by the jQuery, and can be traversed as a Javascript array.